# How i can hide the errors in browser console?

Tags: vue.js, browser, axios

How i can hide the errors in browser console?

[image: Example aimge]

I don't know how to hide these errors in the browser, i am using axios with vuejs

The code is

```
login(user){
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.set('username', user.username);
    formData.set('password', user.password);

    return this._http
        .post(`${baseUrl}/api/auth/login`, formData)
}
```

this._http -> is the axios service

Comment: is this based on laravel?

Comment: no, the backend is python with flask

Comment: @Matheus you can use a catch in the axios promise to handle the error.

Comment: before the code go to catch, show the error message in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch your error this way:

```
export default {
   errorCaptured(err, vm, info) {
       // err: error trace
       // vm: component in which error occured
       // info: Vue specific error information such as lifecycle hooks, events etc.
       // TODO: Perform any custom logic or log to server
       // return false to stop the propagation of errors further to parent or global error 
    handler
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i put this in the a javascript class, because this login funcion, is in a js class

Comment: Put it in the component you call the `login()` function. it handle all errors occured in it.